# How can I add an empty row before a definite row in Python DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I'm working with a huge dataframe in python and sometimes I need to add an empty row or several rows in a definite position to dataframe. For this question I created a small dataframe df in order to show, what I want to achieve.

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])
```

If a row value is 27000, I want to add an empty row before it.
I can insert row after with Concat but I can't really think of a way of adding it before..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a DataFrame with the index labels based on your condition that has all null values. [Assumes `df` has a non-duplicated index]. Then concat and `sort_index` which will place the missing row before (because we concat `df` to `empty`). Then `reset_index` to remove the duplicate index labels.

```
import pandas as pd

empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=df[df.Price.eq(27000)].index)
df = pd.concat([empty, df]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
#            Brand  Price
#0     Honda Civic  22000
#1  Toyota Corolla  25000
#2             NaN    NaN
#3      Ford Focus  27000
#4         Audi A4  35000
```

---

This will add a blank row before **every** 27000 row

```
cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Toyota Corolla','Ford Focus','Audi A4','Jeep'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000,27000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])

empty = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns, index=df[df.Price.eq(27000)].index)
df = pd.concat([empty, df]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
#            Brand  Price
#0     Honda Civic  22000
#1  Toyota Corolla  25000
#2             NaN    NaN
#3      Ford Focus  27000
#4         Audi A4  35000
#5             NaN    NaN
#6            Jeep  27000
```

Comment: Good one..!! visionary (: I didnt think that price can repeat :/

Comment: @anky yeah I wasn't sure if "several rows" meant several rows in one position or several single rows in many positions. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Practically saying this makes more sense than my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a helper cumsum column for groupby then append a blank row only for the first group and then concat:

```
out = pd.concat((g.append(pd.Series(),ignore_index=True) if i==0 else g 
       for i, g in df.groupby(df['Price'].eq(27000).cumsum())))
```

---

```
print(out)

            Brand    Price
0     Honda Civic  22000.0
1  Toyota Corolla  25000.0
2             NaN      NaN
2      Ford Focus  27000.0
3         Audi A4  35000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Let us try `cummax` with `append`:

```
m = df['Price'].eq(27000).cummax()
df[~m].append(pd.Series(), ignore_index=True).append(df[m])
```

---

```
            Brand    Price
0     Honda Civic  22000.0
1  Toyota Corolla  25000.0
2             NaN      NaN
2      Ford Focus  27000.0
3         Audi A4  35000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by `concat()` method  and `apply()` method:

```
result=pd.concat((df.apply(lambda x:np.nan if x['Price']==27000 else x,1),df))
```

Finally use `sort_index()` method,`drop_duplicates()` method and `reset_index()` method:

```
result=result.sort_index(na_position='first').drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now if you print `result` you will get your desired output:

```
    Brand           Price
0   Honda Civic     22000.0
1   Toyota Corolla  25000.0
2   NaN             NaN
3   Ford Focus      27000.0
4   Audi A4         35000.0
```

**This will add a blank row before every row where Price=27000:**

```
result=pd.concat((df.apply(lambda x:np.nan if x['Price']==27000 else x,1),df))

result=result.drop_duplicates().append(result[result.isna().all(1)].iloc[1:]).sort_index(na_position='first').reset_index(drop=True)
```